# Binding data in angular MAT-TABLE with nested interface not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

Trying to bind data from **JSON-SERVER** response into my MAT-TABLE, but getting **ERROR Error: Could not find column with id "ModuleNm"**

**test data**

```
{
  "modules": [
    {
      "Id": 0,
      "ModuleNm": "Visa",
      "UploadDttm": "01/14/2019 21:27",
      
    },
    {
      "Id": 0,
      "ModuleNm": "Visa",
      "UploadDttm": "01/14/2019 21:28",
    },
]
```

**my interface**

```
export interface IModuleType {
   modules: Module[];
}

export interface Module {
    Id:             number;
    ModuleNm:       ModuleNm;
    UploadDttm:     string;
  
}
```

**service**

```
loadData(selectedModuleType: string): Observable<any>{
   return this._http.get<IModuleType[]>(this.testData );
  }
```

**component**

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['ModuleNm', 'UploadDttm',];
dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<IModuleType>;

getData(selectedModule: string): void {
    console.log('loadModuleData mothod :::::>', selectedModule);
    this.test.loadData(selectedModule).subscribe({
      next: (resp) => {
       console.log('RESPONSE IN COMPONENT', typeof resp, resp); // getting object 
       this.dataSource = resp;
        
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.log('Errors :::>', err);
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log('request completed');
      },
    });
  }
```

**html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
       
        <ng-container matColumnDef="ModuleNm">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[0].modules.ModuleNm}} </td>
        </ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
```

Could someone pls help me to understand why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

DataSource accepts an array of objects. Your data seems to be an object which single property is an array - it won't work that way. You need to assign the actual array as a data source.

You could, for example, change the way you assign data to datasource to:

```
// Change the data type of datasource
dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<Module>;

// Change the assignment within subscription
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(resp.modules);
```

And then, in your template, `element` will be representing an item in `modules` array, so for example for the type column change it to:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ModuleNm}} </td>
```